# One-way functions and pseudorandom number generator

Tags: computer-science, cryptography

Is it true that if there is Cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator then there is One-way function?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Maybe you can explain what it is you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a really Cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator you can use it to create a "one time pad" which you can then use to encrypt your message.

One time pad has perfect secrecy (for definition see Shannon or here [lecture notes on perfect secrecy](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~stasio/fall04/lect1.pdf)).

Your function will be a one way function since only you can invert the coded message to it's original plaintextform.

**BUT:** to decipher the message you'll still have to send the pad you've used throu a secure channel or encrypt it with some other cryptosystem .